# Were there any non microscopic integrated circuits?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, history

There is something about history of computer hardware and ICs that confuses me - a jump from wardrobe dimensions of last generation of transistor computers to ICs which were so small as "the size of a little fingernail" (*The Story of the Intel® 4004*). I cannot understand why it had to be so small at the peak of the "any miniaturisation is success" era.

So this leads me to my question: **were there any non microscopic integrated circuits?** By that I mean something that would either not be fabricated with photolithography process or dimensions significantly larger than 10 µm (1971)?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/kilbyctr/jackbuilt.shtml

Comment: What makes you think that computers instantly jumped from wardrobe-sized machines to modern laptops? Moore's law says that the number of transistors doubles every 2 years, so the growth is more of a smooth transition than a instant jump. Just look at this 1997 laptop for something in-between the two sizes: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/WallstreetII.jpg/220px-WallstreetII.jpg

Comment: I don't. But they did jumped from ~1000 transistors packed in large boxes to nail size 2400 components (talking about CPUs). Which is huge deal.

Comment: These? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_integrated_circuit

Comment: Also these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Solid_Logic_Technology, IBM built mainframes from these lego blocks.

Comment: What about the part where they were made of ICs but the whole CPU didn't fit on one IC? The PDP 11/40 is roughly suitcase sized instead of wardrobe sized (but when you add on tape drives, etc, it gets closer to wardrobe sized)

Comment: It was common for  small 'wiring cards' to be used to use transistors (often with DTL ior RTL logic) to implement a single gate or a few gates or part of a gate on a single card. Have a look natv the nphotos [**here**](http://www.oldcalculatormuseum.com/wang360.html) to see what a typical assembled implementation looked like. There are many photos of such boards online. (I have dozens of such boards. )

Comment: [Wang 360e](http://www.oldcalculatormuseum.com/wang360e.html) - good photos, [Friden EC132](http://www.hpmuseum.org/ec132brd.jpg) logic board, [EC132](http://www.hpmuseum.org/ec132.htm), and [Wang 360e - many boards](http://www.dopecc.net/calcat/wang/wang360e-3pics.html) - note circuit links. Example [Logic block, switch & amplifiers](http://www.dopecc.net/calcat/wang/images/W360E-PCB0511-f.jpg) - cans are transistors and see diagram at lower left of circuits and table of resistor values.

Answer (score 1):

The computer controlling the wing-pivoting of the F-15, implementing sensors and aerodynamic computations, needed 10 to 20 ICs about 1970.

The people at Fairchild used standard reflex camera dual-lenses in their first optical lithography; resolution was about 50 microns (2 mils, or 0.002 inches).

Comment: Thanks, would that be something like 7400 series - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series ?

Comment: The early Fairchild devices were RTL, resistor-transistor-logic. The moon-landers used only uL914 dual NOR gates. No flipflops.

Answer (score 0):

As John points out in his comment, the first transistor was already pretty small but not microscopic. After that was invented, computer processors would not have been integrated into a single chip until many years later. Between those two points, you have a varying amount of integration with a single computer being made up of many different IC's. The basic IC's would have been inverters/nands/nors and amplifiers on single chips all wired together to make up the entire computer.

In a way, you're right though, microprocessors made a significant jump in miniturization vs mainframes because they were addressing a different market. You could think of mainframes being that era's equivalent of a server computer and the original microprocessor being that era's equivalent of a microcontroller. While they're both computer brains, their functions are designed for completely different applications.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware_(1960s%E2%80%93present)

Answer (score 0):

The first integrated circuits were in [vacuum tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewe_3NF), and definitely bigger than 10um, and definitely not lithographic.

http://www.computerhistory.org/siliconengine/timeline/